# Python 3.4, How to increase the size of the tkinter spinbox widget arrowheads?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

How do you increase the size of the tkinter spinbox arrowheads?

```
root = Tk()
Rtitle = Frame(root)

valueChanger = Spinbox(Rtitle, from_=0, to=10, wrap = True, width = 0)

valueChanger.pack(side=RIGHT, padx = 5, ipadx = 2, ipady = 5)

Rtitle.pack(side = TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrow buttons are each half the height of the box.  Increase the box height by increasing the font size.  Minimal complete verifiable example (of the sort people should post when asking questions ;-):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

root = Tk()
spin = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=9, width=3,
               font=Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold'))
spin.pack()
```

Comment: I learned the answer by experiment, starting with `Spinbox(root)`, and without the font import.  I did not know for sure that expanding the box with a large font would expand the arrow boxes, as opposed to putting space between them, until I tried it.

Comment: It was a good idea to try that, I new to Tkinter and it appears experimentation is key. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ttk, you can configure arrowsize without changing the font.
(I'm on OS X, so I needed to set the theme, too.)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('My.TSpinbox', arrowsize=15)

sb1 = ttk.Spinbox(root, style='TSpinbox', from_=1, to=5)
sb1.grid()

sb2 = ttk.Spinbox(root, style='My.TSpinbox', from_=1, to=5)
sb2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```